# When using [isAnimated] this generates an error

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

As per this [documentation for ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/collapse)

I'm trying to animate the collapse as per the docs, they use a `[isAnimated]` attribute:

```
<div id="collapseBasic" [collapse]="isCollapsed" [isAnimated]="true">
  <div class="well well-lg card card-block card-header">Some content</div>
</div>
```

However I get this error

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'isAnimated' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
</button>
<hr>
<div id="collapseBasic" [collapse]="isCollapsed" [ERROR ->][isAnimated]="true">
```

My .ts file looks like

```
import {Component, TemplateRef, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CollapseModule, ModalModule, BsModalService, BsModalRef} from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.scss']
})

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CollapseModule.forRoot()
  ]
})

export class MobileBasketSummaryCheckoutComponent {
  BrowserAnimationsModule;
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  CollapseModule;
  BsModalRef;
  isCollapsed = false;
  isAnimated = false;

  config = {
    animated: true,
    keyboard: true
  };
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, this.config);
  }
}
```

I've tried importing in different ways but I don't quite understand as the error seems to suggest that it's the property being binded to `div` that's an issue.

I expect the output to compile / work and for the toggle to animate

Answer (score 0):

isCollapsed variable to specify the type  `boolean` in view side *ngIf="isCollapsed"

```
isCollapsed:boolean=true;

isAnimated:boolean=false;
```

Try this :

```
import {Component, TemplateRef, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CollapseModule, ModalModule, BsModalService, BsModalRef} from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.scss']
})

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CollapseModule.forRoot()
  ]
})

export class MobileBasketSummaryCheckoutComponent {
  BrowserAnimationsModule;
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  CollapseModule;
  BsModalRef;
  isCollapsed:boolean=true;
  isAnimated:boolean=false;

  config = {
    animated: true,
    keyboard: true
  };
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, this.config);
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work I get the same error `Can't bind to 'isAnimated' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`

Comment: add this line and give following ngOnInit() { isCollapsed:boolean=true;

isAnimated:boolean=false; }  in view side *ngIf="isCollapsed"

Answer (score 0):

On component add: `ngIf="isCollapsed"`

This works for me

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
    ngIf="isCollapsed"; // just add this
    isCollapsed = true;
    constructor()
```